# Search Program using python

Tags: python, search, python-2.7

I am coding a search program in python which take the folder for searching for the file as a system argument(sys.argv). It then asks for name of the file to find.
**What is the problem**
 1. How do I know which files or folders are there in the folder? Is there any module or function for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os

for item in os.listdir(path):
    if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, item)):
        print "Folder"
    else:
        print "File"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stuff from `os` and `os.path`.

```
import os

path = "xyz"

files = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,x))]
directories = [x for x in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,x))]
```

This is a rather elegant solution, though this iterates over all entries of os.listdir twice.

Answer (score 0):

This lists all the files in the specified path:

```
import os

#Change the value of path to a path.
path = "D:\\Pythonic\\"

stuff_in_path = os.listdir(path)
for x in stuff_in_path:
    print x
```