# Listing folders in current working directory

Tags: python, directory

How can I get the list of folders in current working directory in Python?
I need only the folders, not files or sub-folders.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141291/how-to-list-only-top-level-directories-in-python

Answer (score 3):

Simple list comprehension:

```
[fn for fn in os.listdir(u'.') if os.path.isdir(fn)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@ATOzTOA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14275405/1931274)
You can use `os.listdir` and `os.path.isfile` like here:

```
import os

path = 'whatever your path is'

for item in os.listdir(path):
    if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, item)):
        print "Folder: ",item
    else:
        print "File: ",item
```

Now you know what are folders and what are files.
Since you don't want files, you can simply store the folders (path or name) in a list
For that, Do this:

```
import os

path = 'whatever your path is'
folders = [] # list that will contain folders (path+name)

for item in os.listdir(path):
    if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, item)):
        folders.append(os.path.join(path, item)) #  os.path.join(path, item) is your folder path
```

Comment: @AhmetSezginDuran Added some more code, see that too. Also, pls accept this answer it it helped...